# tailwind ccs styles not reflecting on the Svelte project (localhost)

Tags: syntax-error, tailwind-css, svelte

I have followed the instruction on https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/sveltekit
Install Tailwind CSS with SvelteKit, however the styles do not reflect on the project.
Get the error "unkown at rule @tailwind[image]

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
  kit: {
    adapter: adapter()
  },
  preprocess: vitePreprocess()
};

export default config;
```

Comment: is normal... should work fine even with that. I create 5+ projects with svelteKit and Tailwind and it doesn't give any problem with that warning. if it works don't charge the code there in the CSS file. for experience is a vscode warning. you can desactivate it if you want to

Comment: /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{html,js,svelte,ts}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {}
  },
  plugins: []
};                                                 is this tailwind.config.cjs file correct

Comment: I have now added the link in the app.html file and it is is finally working.

Comment: <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>